# Не срабатывает код в контроллере laravel

Tags: laravel

Не работает код в контроллере. Форма обрабатывается, при нажатии на кнопку должен срабатывать контроллер, который записывает данные в бд. Код внутри контроллера не срабатывает. При нажатии на кнопку просто перезагружается страница (по крайней мере, это так выглядит), ошибок никаких не выдает.

web.php:

```
Route::post('/post/{id}/submit', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'postCommentSubmit'])->name('postCommentSubmit');
```

PostController:

```
public function postCommentSubmit($id, PostRequest $data) {
  //здесь код, который не выполняется, не происходит даже редирект
return redirect()->route('home');
```

}

comments.blade.php:

```
        <form action="{{ route('postCommentSubmit', $post[0]->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your answer"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, вероятно, в реквесте. Попробуйте убрать входные параметры из контроллера и dd'шнуть из него. Если сработает - повторить с реквестом. Так Вы локализируете ошибку и поймете в чем дело. Помимо это хотел бы дать небольшой совет. Вам не обязательно передавать в контроллер id поста, чтоб потом искать модель. Вместо этого Вы можете передавать саму модель. Для этого нужно в RouteSurviceProvider в методе boot() зарегистрировать Вашу модель таким образом:

```
Route::model('post', \App\Models\Post::class);
```

Затем в роуте прописать не

```
Route::post('/post/{id}/submit'...
```

а

```
Route::post('/post/{post}/submit'
```

В контроллере же входным параметром указать

```
public function postCommentSubmit(PostRequest $data, Post $post) { ...
```

Не забудьте сбросить кэш роутов.